# How to select rows based on column value string checking?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.loc[df['name'] == 'Mary']
```

The above get rows if the 'name' is Mary. What about if I want rows that contains 'Mary', not exactly equal 'Mary'?

Comment: use `df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('Mary')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.str.contains()` method to achieve this.

```
df[df['name'].str.contains('Mary')]
```

Comment: Is '|' is a special character that doesn't work with the contains function? I used df[df['name'].str.contains('|')] and it selected all rows.

Comment: try to escape the symbol by writing df[df['name'].str.contains('\|')]